# karate DSL - Is there a way to display a PDF file in cucumber report?

Tags: karate

Is there a way to display a PDF file in karate DSL - cucumber report? Our HTTP server response is PDF statement and if we display in steps that will be help to review the results at later time. (same with images type response also).

Answer (score 0):

Not yet and I just opened a feature request: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/558

For now you can use the `print` syntax and that would appear in the reports.

EDIT: this is implemented in 0.9.0 onwards: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-embed

Comment: Thanks Peter. Looking forward for this.

Comment: @Umeshkandhalu can you try the new RC version: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1052074943721160704